# building an array in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have:

```
arr_1 = tf.random_uniform([3],0.1,0.2)
arr_2 = tf.random_uniform([3],-0.1,0.1)
```

I am trying to create an `arr_3` which has a size of `6` and alternates elements from `arr_1` and `arr_2`. How should I go about this? Since tensors are read-only as such, I don't think I can index them and assign values the same way I would with numpy. Any solutions?

Comment: Why not first do that using numpy and convert `arr_3` into tensor?

Comment: I am doing this inside a map function for an object of the Dataset API. If I use numpy functions, it does not generate a random number of every single call, but instead uses the number it generated in the first call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work. The idea is based on stacking the data and then flattening it.

```
arr_3 = tf.reshape(tf.stack([arr_1, arr_2], axis=1), [-1]))
```